# Multisite: menus can't be added in child sites

Tags: menus, multisite

It seems that we cannot add menus in child sites in multisite. Did anyone face this issue before?

I have the Menu container enabled in my functions.php

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
        'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
    )
);
```

I can add menus to the parent site. But I can't do it in the child sites even though I can see the Menu container and the Create Menu button.

No menu is created when the Create Menu button is clicked. WordPress just refreshed the page and the menu I tried to create is not present at all.

I have inspected the database of my child site and I can't find any row for `nav_menu_item`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I also found out that I cannot add any category or tag in my child sites. Why??

Attached some screenshots as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try switching to a default theme and disable all the plugin for the subsite? Possibly the theme active in the sub site is not registering any menu.

Comment: @Kumar done that. still the same